# facebook api, images url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, interface-builder, xfbml

When I paste a link on my Facebook automatically reads the url and assigned me a picture of them on my server etngo as I can do to take a default image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set your og: tags on the web page.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ pay attention to `og:image`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, now how long it takes to update the cache of facebook?

Comment: Lint the URL, and the cache is flushed immediately. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint